# Designing and implementing mobile web application

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jquery-mobile

I would like to design and implement a mobile web application using JQuery mobile and Java EE technology.

The application will consists of sales persons using the mobile device to take an order when they visit the customers. So the application will contain complex business logic.

I am confused as to with what frameworks I should pick/select to design and implement the server side of the application. So my question is should I use Spring, Spring MVC and Hibernate together or some other suggestion?

But I want to stick to Java technology as I am comfortable with it.

My next question is how will the JQuery mobile and the server side integrate with each other. I mean what are the ways/methods to integrate them?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to avoid Spring in this case.

Use straight Java EE, with JAX-RS, CDI/EJB and JPA.

Your jQuery code will call JAX-RS resources (which are ReSTfull web services). Those resources are injected with Service beans, which are a combination of CDI and EJB. These beans will contain your super complex business logic. If they need to retrieve or store something from/into the DB, they will use JPA for this via an injected entity manager.

Comment: thanks for your comment. By the way what makes you say to avoid Spring. What about Spring MVC

Comment: Well that's not really accurate. See, for example, http://codetutr.com/2013/04/09/spring-mvc-easy-rest-based-json-services-with-responsebody/ for examples of JSON/XML from Spring MVC rather than HTML being rendered.

Comment: @alanhay right... But why would you use that when there's already JAX-RS to use in Java EE? I'm not really sure, but I would guess JAX-RS integrates better with CDI which is clearly a better and more modern model than old Spring. Anyway, just throwing out the obvious choice here. If OP already decided he wants to use Spring, then fine, but why ask here for other suggestions?

Comment: The original poster was asking about the suitability of Spring and for any other alternatives. I fail to see where he has said he has already decided to use Spring otherwise, as you say, why ask. I might as well have said don't use old heavyweight EJB technology but of course it's moved on since then: much like Spring has over the years.

Comment: @AlanHay okay, fair enough ;)

Comment: @AlanHay thanks for the explanation.so you recon to use Spring MVC, hibernate with JQuery Mobile. Can you please also try to answer my second question regarding " how will the JQuery mobile and the server side integrate with each other"

Comment: I wan't really recommending either. I'm sure recent versions of both Spring and JEE6 have the features you will require. If you're already familiar with Spring then I don't see any reason not to use it. If not then have a look at both and see what they offer.

Comment: @AlanHay
Can you please also try to answer my second question regarding " how will the JQuery mobile and the server side integrate with each other"